# Is it OK to paint MDF only with primer?

Tags: painting, primer, mdf

I am working on a garage cabinet project and I used MDF as the material. I used a white primer for 2 coats and I like the result already. Can I leave it like this or I have to paint it with a proper paint? Basically can primer be used as paint?

Comment: it's not as durable or easy to clean.  It's not going to protect your MDF from swelling if you get water on it.  So really it's up to what your expectations are of the cabinet.  I have bare MDF shelves in my garage.

Comment: I will paint a small piece and run tests on it (dirt, water,  scratch, etc) and decide later. I will update this post afterward.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't leave it as-is as long as you are happy with the appearance.  A lot of new homes in large developments don't have much more on the walls either.

You could have also used a primer/paint combo product and not have to apply any additional layers at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have a problem with it. I built cabinets using mdf from Home Depot recently and was soaking small pieces of it in water for days to see what would happen to it and nothing ever did.